# QuotaExceededError using MediaStream API

Tags: javascript, video, media-source

My application receives some video chunks from a ServerSentEvent (SSE) and, using MediaStream API, it should append them in a buffer and visualize them into an HTML5 video tag.
The problem is MediaSource API, that stops working when the program tries to append a chunk to the mediaStream buffer.

The error appears when the program tries to append the first chunk.

This is the client-side code:

```
window.MediaSource = window.MediaSource || window.WebKitMediaSource;
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
if (!!!window.MediaSource) {alert('MediaSource API is not available');}

var video = document.getElementById("video");
var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) {
    var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:5000/video');
    // this is the line that catch the error
    var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');

    source.addEventListener('chunkStreamed', function(e){
        var chunk = new Blob(JSON.parse(e.data));
        console.log("chunk: ", chunk);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            // error is caused by this line
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(e.target.result));
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
    });

    source.addEventListener('endStreaming', function(e){
        console.log(e.data);
        // mediaSource.endOfStream();
        // endOfStream() not here, sourceBuffer.appendBuffer will done after this command and will cause InvalidStateError 
    });

    source.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("EventSource open");
    };

    source.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        source.close();
    };

}, false);
```

and this is the complete error log:

```
Uncaught QuotaExceededError: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota.
```

The problem comes out when the app tries to do `sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(e.target.result));`.
I really can't understand way this error appear. Code is really 
like the code of [this example](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html)

Comment: MediaSource is kind of in a weird place at the moment.  It's subtle, but the example you link to seems to be broken in the current release versions of chrome and firefox (the [video](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/test.webm) is supposed to be 6 seconds long). I've been trying to follow the implementation of mediasource, and I don't know of any example that works 100% as of this posting.

Comment: Oh my god!!! I didn't see that video was 6 second long! :(

Anyway it's able to attach the video, but I don't...

Comment: I need this feature for a prototype program, then also if it's not perfect it's ok... ;) Some idea for the reason of the `QuotaExceededError`?

Comment: It [looks like it's thrown when it "can't handle any more `sourcebuffer` objects"](https://github.com/yoavweiss/Blink/blob/master/Source/modules/mediasource/MediaSource.cpp). I couldn't say what might be causing that.

Comment: I like the idea of using an `EventSource` but it it is not suited to carrying a binary payload. probably better to use a `WebSocket` or `XMLHttpRequest` with `responseType = 'arraybuffer'`

Comment: Does your error appear immediately upon the first attempt to call `appendBuffer` or after a certain amount of calls to the method?